# How to search system files and list them in windows 7 and above using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to search all systems files on windows 7 and above versions of windows.

Besides I want to list them in a txt file.

Can somebody please provide me a code snippet including exception handling for UAC?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isnt a code writing service.

Comment: @James Wood, I am just asking for snippet not complete program, if somebody provide me guidance it will also do.

Comment: DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("path");
            string[] systemFiles = info.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.Attributes == FileAttributes.System).Select(y => y.FullName).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it

**Get files from directory**

```
using System.IO;

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

**Get files from directory (with specified extension)**

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp");
// returns:
// "c:\MyDir\my-car.BMP"
```

**Get files from directory (including all subdirectories)**

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp",
                                         SearchOption.AllDirectories);
// returns:
// "c:\MyDir\my-car.BMP"
// "c:\MyDir\Friends\james.BMP"
```

How save array like .txt file? Like this.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open("scores.txt"))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    scoreArray.ForEach(r=>sw.WriteLine(r));
}
```